# How can I detect addition of <li> tag in DOM using MutationObserver in JavaScript and get data-filename inside an IFRAME?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am working on a CRM system where I can only write javascript in onloadfunc. My intenton is get data-filename from newly added li tag to the DOM and send notifications. Please note that my targetNode is inside an IFRAME. I have many other upload fields besides this upload field. My code is working with no Iframe but it is not working in this situation.

```js
var targetNode = document.getElementById('filelist_cf_1267610');
var config = {childList: true, subtree: true };

var ActiveDraftsCallback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }            
       }
    }
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(ActiveDraftsCallback);
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

```html
<iframe name="win_lst" id="win_lst" src="fp_list.jsp?fieldid=1267609&amp;codedid=QHJrJ0keIhgKFlALJGc1KgRXEAcuXRsTH2JcU0VNZl8~&amp;uptype=0" frameborder="0">
   <html lang="en">
      <head>        
      <body style="background:#FFFFFF">
         <div id="uploaded-filelist" class="uploaded-filelist">
            <form action="fp_list.jsp" method="POST">
               <input type="hidden" name="ss_formtoken" id="ss_formtoken" value="60B19CD9C086ED81DC1FC23B65D6E9942F94BEEEA96F60CAA533B8705E6D013A">
               <input type="hidden" name="fieldid" value="1267609">
               <input type="hidden" name="codedid" value="QHJrJ0keIhgKFlALJGc1KgRXEAcuXRsTH2JcU0VNZl8~">
               <input type="hidden" name="uptype" value="0">
               <input type="hidden" name="isanno" value="0">
               <input type="hidden" name="delefile" id="delefile" value="">
               <div id="updatedresult" style="display:none">
                  <div id="cf_1267609" style="display:inline-block"><button type="button" class="Button" name="iconbutton" aria-label="Upload" title="" onclick="x_uploadfolder(1267609,'QHJrJ0keIhgKFlALJGc1KgRXEAcuXRsTH2JcU0VNZl8~','File Manager')" data-original-title="Upload"><i class="fa fa-upload" style="cursor:pointer" data-original-title="" title=""></i></button><button type="button" class="Button" name="iconbutton" title="" aria-label="Merge Files" onclick="x_mergefile(1267609,-1,'QHJrJ0keIhgKFlALJGc1KgRXEAcuXRsTH2JcU0VNZl8~')" data-original-title="Merge Files"><i class="fa fa-clone" style="cursor:pointer" data-original-title="" title=""></i></button><button type="button" onclick="ssUploadedFileList.confirmDeleteFiles(1267609,1127956,80,null,'Delete File(s)','Are you sure you want to delete the following file(s)?')" class="btn btn-default faButton DisabledButton" id="delete_1267609" name="delete_1267609" data-original-title="Delete Selected Files" aria-label="Delete Selected Files" disabled=""><i class="fa fa-trash" style="cursor:pointer" data-original-title="" title=""></i></button></div>
                  <i class="fa fa-history fa-lg text-help Pointer" onclick="openinmwin('/s_cusfieldhistory.jsp?ismwin=1&amp;appid=102946&amp;objectid=1127956&amp;fieldid=1267609');" id="his_1267609" title="" aria-label="History" data-original-title="History"></i>
                  <div class="toggleButtonGroup"><button type="button" onclick="ssUploadedFileList.toggleListView(1081636,1267609)" class="btn btn-default faButton buttonToggle active" id="gridviewbtn_1267609" name="gridviewbtn_1267609" data-original-title="Grid View" disabled=""><i class="fa fa-th-large" style="cursor:pointer" data-original-title="" title=""></i></button><button type="button" onclick="ssUploadedFileList.toggleListView(1081636,1267609)" class="btn btn-default faButton buttonToggle" id="listviewbtn_1267609" name="listviewbtn_1267609" data-original-title="List View"><i class="fa fa-list" style="cursor:pointer" data-original-title="" title=""></i></button></div>
                  <div class="ssUploadedFileList" data-orderby="date|desc">
                     <ul id="filelist_cf_1267609" class="">
                        <li class="ssUploadedFileList-listViewHeader"><span>&nbsp;</span><span data-sorttype="filename"><span>File Name</span><i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-original-title="" title=""></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-original-title="" title=""></i></span><span data-sorttype="size"><span>Size</span><i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-original-title="" title=""></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-original-title="" title=""></i></span><span data-sorttype="date"><span>Date</span><i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-original-title="" title=""></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-original-title="" title=""></i></span><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
                        <li data-filename="Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf" data-size="824" data-date="1540390632018">
                           <div class="ssUploadedFileList-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="uploadedFileSet1267609" id="uploadedFileSet1267609-0" data-fieldid="1267609" data-fileicon="fa fa-file-pdf-o" value="Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf"><span>&nbsp;</span><label for="uploadedFileSet1267609-0" class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></label></div>
                           <span id="details_1127956_1267609_1" class="ssUploadedFileList-details" style="width:calc(100% - 75px)"><span id="span_file_1127956_1267609_1"><a href="/files/spool/404048/1127956/80_1267609_1127956/Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf?fs=1" title="Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf" target="_blank">Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf</a></span><span>824 KB - 2018-10-24 10:17am</span></span><span id="renamespan_1127956_1267609_1" class="renamespan" style="width:calc(100% - 136px); display:none"><input id="renamefile_1127956_1267609_1" value="Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf" class="ignoreChange" style="width:calc(100% - 15px)"><span>824 KB - 2018-10-24 10:17am</span></span><span class="ssUploadedFileList-size">824 KB</span><span class="ssUploadedFileList-date">2018-10-24 10:17am</span>
                           <div id="options_1127956_1267609_1" class="ssUploadedFileList-options">
                              <span aria-label="Options"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" title="" data-original-title="Options"></i></span>
                              <ul>
                                 <li onclick="ssUploadedFileList.confirmDeleteFiles(1267609,1127956,80,'Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf','Delete File(s)','Are you sure you want to delete the following file(s)?')">Delete</li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>
                           <span id="renamebut_1127956_1267609_1" class="renamebuttons" style="display:none"><span onclick="ssUploadedFileList.cancelRename(1267609,1127956,1)"><i class="fa fa-times" title="" data-original-title="Cancel"></i></span><span onclick="ssUploadedFileList.saveRename(1267609,1127956,80,1,'Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf')"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" title="" data-original-title="Save"></i></span></span>
                        </li>
                        <li data-filename="111mergefile_180904.pdf" data-size="283" data-date="1536094080018">
                           <div class="ssUploadedFileList-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="uploadedFileSet1267609" id="uploadedFileSet1267609-1" data-fieldid="1267609" data-fileicon="fa fa-file-pdf-o" value="111mergefile_180904.pdf"><span>&nbsp;</span><label for="uploadedFileSet1267609-1" class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></label></div>
                           <span id="details_1127956_1267609_2" class="ssUploadedFileList-details" style="width:calc(100% - 75px)"><span id="span_file_1127956_1267609_2"><a href="/files/spool/404048/1127956/80_1267609_1127956/111mergefile_180904.pdf?fs=1" title="111mergefile_180904.pdf" target="_blank">111mergefile_180904.pdf</a></span><span>283 KB - 2018-09-04 4:47pm</span></span><span id="renamespan_1127956_1267609_2" class="renamespan" style="width:calc(100% - 136px); display:none"><input id="renamefile_1127956_1267609_2" value="111mergefile_180904.pdf" class="ignoreChange" style="width:calc(100% - 15px)"><span>283 KB - 2018-09-04 4:47pm</span></span><span class="ssUploadedFileList-size">283 KB</span><span class="ssUploadedFileList-date">2018-09-04 4:47pm</span>
                           <div id="options_1127956_1267609_2" class="ssUploadedFileList-options">
                              <span aria-label="Options"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" title="" data-original-title="Options"></i></span>
                              <ul>
                                 <li onclick="ssUploadedFileList.confirmDeleteFiles(1267609,1127956,80,'111mergefile_180904.pdf','Delete File(s)','Are you sure you want to delete the following file(s)?')">Delete</li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>
                           <span id="renamebut_1127956_1267609_2" class="renamebuttons" style="display:none"><span onclick="ssUploadedFileList.cancelRename(1267609,1127956,2)"><i class="fa fa-times" title="" data-original-title="Cancel"></i></span><span onclick="ssUploadedFileList.saveRename(1267609,1127956,80,2,'111mergefile_180904.pdf')"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" title="" data-original-title="Save"></i></span></span>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                     <div class="ssUploadedFileList-footer"><span class="total">Total Files: 2</span></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div id="updatedpdfresult" style="display:none"></div>
               <div id="cf_1267609_container">
                  <div id="cf_1267609" style="display:inline-block"><button type="button" onclick="ssUploadedFileList.confirmDeleteFiles(1267609,1127956,80,null,'Delete File(s)','Are you sure you want to delete the following file(s)?')" class="btn btn-default faButton DisabledButton" id="delete_1267609" name="delete_1267609" data-original-title="Delete Selected Files" aria-label="Delete Selected Files" disabled=""><i class="fa fa-trash" style="cursor:pointer" data-original-title="" title=""></i></button></div>
                  <div class="toggleButtonGroup"><button type="button" onclick="ssUploadedFileList.toggleListView(1081636,1267609)" class="btn btn-default faButton buttonToggle active" id="gridviewbtn_1267609" name="gridviewbtn_1267609" data-original-title="Grid View" disabled=""><i class="fa fa-th-large" style="cursor:pointer" data-original-title="" title=""></i></button><button type="button" onclick="ssUploadedFileList.toggleListView(1081636,1267609)" class="btn btn-default faButton buttonToggle" id="listviewbtn_1267609" name="listviewbtn_1267609" data-original-title="List View"><i class="fa fa-list" style="cursor:pointer" data-original-title="" title=""></i></button></div>
                  <div class="ssUploadedFileList" data-orderby="date|desc">
                     <ul id="filelist_cf_1267609" class="">
                        <li class="ssUploadedFileList-listViewHeader"><span>&nbsp;</span><span data-sorttype="filename"><span>File Name</span><i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-original-title="" title=""></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-original-title="" title=""></i></span><span data-sorttype="size"><span>Size</span><i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-original-title="" title=""></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-original-title="" title=""></i></span><span data-sorttype="date" class="descending"><span>Date</span><i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-original-title="" title=""></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-original-title="" title=""></i></span><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
                        <li data-filename="Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf" data-size="824" data-date="1540390632018">
                           <div class="ssUploadedFileList-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="uploadedFileSet1267609" id="uploadedFileSet1267609-0" data-fieldid="1267609" data-fileicon="fa fa-file-pdf-o" value="Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf"><span>&nbsp;</span><label for="uploadedFileSet1267609-0" class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></label></div>
                           <span id="details_1127956_1267609_1" class="ssUploadedFileList-details" style="width:calc(100% - 75px)"><span id="span_file_1127956_1267609_1"><a href="/files/spool/404048/1127956/80_1267609_1127956/Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf?fs=1" title="Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf" target="_blank">Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf</a></span><span>824 KB - 2018-10-24 10:17am</span></span><span id="renamespan_1127956_1267609_1" class="renamespan" style="width:calc(100% - 136px); display:none"><input id="renamefile_1127956_1267609_1" value="Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf" class="ignoreChange" style="width:calc(100% - 15px)"><span>824 KB - 2018-10-24 10:17am</span></span><span class="ssUploadedFileList-size">824 KB</span><span class="ssUploadedFileList-date">2018-10-24 10:17am</span>
                           <div id="options_1127956_1267609_1" class="ssUploadedFileList-options">
                              <span aria-label="Options"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" title="" data-original-title="Options"></i></span>
                              <ul>
                                 <li onclick="ssUploadedFileList.confirmDeleteFiles(1267609,1127956,80,'Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf','Delete File(s)','Are you sure you want to delete the following file(s)?')">Delete</li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>
                           <span id="renamebut_1127956_1267609_1" class="renamebuttons" style="display:none"><span onclick="ssUploadedFileList.cancelRename(1267609,1127956,1)"><i class="fa fa-times" title="" data-original-title="Cancel"></i></span><span onclick="ssUploadedFileList.saveRename(1267609,1127956,80,1,'Form1-Assessment-of-Attendant-Care-Needs-User-Manual.pdf')"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" title="" data-original-title="Save"></i></span></span>
                        </li>
                        <li data-filename="111mergefile_180904.pdf" data-size="283" data-date="1536094080018">
                           <div class="ssUploadedFileList-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="uploadedFileSet1267609" id="uploadedFileSet1267609-1" data-fieldid="1267609" data-fileicon="fa fa-file-pdf-o" value="111mergefile_180904.pdf"><span>&nbsp;</span><label for="uploadedFileSet1267609-1" class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></label></div>
                           <span id="details_1127956_1267609_2" class="ssUploadedFileList-details" style="width:calc(100% - 75px)"><span id="span_file_1127956_1267609_2"><a href="/files/spool/404048/1127956/80_1267609_1127956/111mergefile_180904.pdf?fs=1" title="111mergefile_180904.pdf" target="_blank">111mergefile_180904.pdf</a></span><span>283 KB - 2018-09-04 4:47pm</span></span><span id="renamespan_1127956_1267609_2" class="renamespan" style="width:calc(100% - 136px); display:none"><input id="renamefile_1127956_1267609_2" value="111mergefile_180904.pdf" class="ignoreChange" style="width:calc(100% - 15px)"><span>283 KB - 2018-09-04 4:47pm</span></span><span class="ssUploadedFileList-size">283 KB</span><span class="ssUploadedFileList-date">2018-09-04 4:47pm</span>
                           <div id="options_1127956_1267609_2" class="ssUploadedFileList-options">
                              <span aria-label="Options"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" title="" data-original-title="Options"></i></span>
                              <ul>
                                 <li onclick="ssUploadedFileList.confirmDeleteFiles(1267609,1127956,80,'111mergefile_180904.pdf','Delete File(s)','Are you sure you want to delete the following file(s)?')">Delete</li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>
                           <span id="renamebut_1127956_1267609_2" class="renamebuttons" style="display:none"><span onclick="ssUploadedFileList.cancelRename(1267609,1127956,2)"><i class="fa fa-times" title="" data-original-title="Cancel"></i></span><span onclick="ssUploadedFileList.saveRename(1267609,1127956,80,2,'111mergefile_180904.pdf')"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" title="" data-original-title="Save"></i></span></span>
                        </li>                     </ul>
               
                  </div>
               </div>

</form>
</div>
</body></html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: What's your question? Is the code working or not? If it's not working, what is it doing instead of what you expect?

Comment: It is not detecting additional of new li when I upload a new file to the control.

Comment: I tried your code. I added a button to do `targetNode.appendChild(newLI);`, and when I clicked the button I got the log message.

Comment: You have an extra `}` in your `ActiveDraftsCallback`, I had to fix that syntax error to get the code to work. Is that in the original code or a copying error?

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93Lkwt5u/6/): may it help you?

Comment: The targetNode itself may be swapped so try to observe an element higher in the DOM tree e.g. body.

Comment: Hi All, Karen Grigoryan your code is working. My code is even working too but I just realize that my upload field is inside iframe which is why my code is not working. I just uploaded html with iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just watch the `childList` you don't need to filter mutations by `type`, because they are all going to be of type `childList`.

So just `forEach` through mutations and `console.log` the every first `addedNodes`

```js
var targetNode = document.getElementById('filelist_cf_1267610');
var config = {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

var ActiveDraftsCallback = function(mutations, observer) {
  mutations.forEach(({
    addedNodes
  }) => {

    const li = addedNodes[0];
    if (li && li.nodeName == 'LI') {
      console.log(li.getAttribute("data-filename"));
    }
  });
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(ActiveDraftsCallback);
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// imitate adding a li in 2secs

const li = document.createElement("li");
li.setAttribute("data-filename", "test");

setTimeout(() => {document.getElementById("filelist_cf_1267610").appendChild(li)}, 2000);
```

```html
<ul id="filelist_cf_1267610" class="listView">
  <li class="ssUploadedFileList-listViewHeader"><span>&nbsp;</span><span data-sorttype="filename"><span>File Name</span><i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-original-title="" title=""></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-original-title="" title=""></i></span><span data-sorttype="size"><span>Size</span>
    <i
      class="fa fa-caret-up" data-original-title="" title=""></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-original-title="" title=""></i></span><span data-sorttype="date" class="descending"><span>Date</span><i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-original-title="" title=""></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-original-title=""
        title=""></i></span><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
  <li data-filename="asif.pdf" data-size="74" data-date="1544642199018">
    <div class="ssUploadedFileList-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="uploadedFileSet1267610" id="uploadedFileSet1267610-0" data-fieldid="1267610" data-fileicon="fa fa-file-pdf-o" value="asif.pdf"><span>&nbsp;</span><label for="uploadedFileSet1267610-0" class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></label></div>
    <span id="details_1127956_1267610_1" class="ssUploadedFileList-details" style="width:calc(100% - 75px)"><span id="span_file_1127956_1267610_1"><a href="/files/spool/404048/1127956/80_1267610_1127956/asif.pdf?fs=1" title="asif.pdf" target="_blank">asif.pdf</a></span><span>74 KB - 2018-12-12 2:16pm</span></span>
    <span
      id="renamespan_1127956_1267610_1" class="renamespan" style="width:calc(100% - 136px); display:none"><input id="renamefile_1127956_1267610_1" value="asif.pdf" class="ignoreChange" style="width:calc(100% - 15px)"><span>74 KB - 2018-12-12 2:16pm</span></span><span class="ssUploadedFileList-size">74 KB</span><span class="ssUploadedFileList-date">2018-12-12 2:16pm</span>
      <div id="options_1127956_1267610_1" class="ssUploadedFileList-options">
        <span aria-label="Options"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" title="" data-original-title="Options"></i></span>
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li onclick="ssUploadedFileList.confirmDeleteFiles(1267610,1127956,80,'asif.pdf','Delete File(s)','Are you sure you want to delete the following file(s)?')">Delete</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <span id="renamebut_1127956_1267610_1" class="renamebuttons" style="display:none"><span onclick="ssUploadedFileList.cancelRename(1267610,1127956,1)"><i class="fa fa-times" title="" data-original-title="Cancel"></i></span><span onclick="ssUploadedFileList.saveRename(1267610,1127956,80,1,'asif.pdf')"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" title="" data-original-title="Save"></i></span></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```